# Make gulp-scp2 ask for password

Tags: javascript, gulp, scp

I'm using gulp to move some folders in a remote directory via scp. Actually if I declare the password in the gulpfile it works fine. I rather want the password is required every time I try to run this task by the prompt, and not to put it visible in the file.
How can I do that?

My gulp task:

```
var scp = require('gulp-scp2');

gulp.task('deploy', function(done) {
    return gulp.src("./dist/**")
    .pipe(scp({
        host: 'localhost',
        username: 'saifer',
        dest: '/home/saifer/'
        }))
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        });
   });
```

Starting the task this way obviously throws an error like:

```
Error: Authentication failure. Available authentication methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
```

I'm looking for something to add the scp's passing object to let the gulp taks ask for a password before trying to connect

Comment: I did see this https://github.com/brechtpm/gulp-deploy-ssh another package which apparently does prompt for the password (but has poor documentation).

Answer (score 0):

I believe prompting is an unrelenting problem. You should solve it with a separate module(or just with readline module from standard library). The solution below uses the `prompt` module:

```
const util = require('util')
const prompt = require('prompt')

var schema = {
  properties: {
    password: {
      hidden: true
    }
  }
};

prompt.start();

util.promisify(prompt.get)(schema).then(({ password }) => {
  var scp = require('gulp-scp2');

  gulp.task('deploy', function(done) {
    return gulp.src("./dist/**")
      .pipe(scp({
        host: 'localhost',
        username: 'saifer',
        dest: '/home/saifer/',
        password
      }))
      .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: @Saifer any reaction?)

Comment: Probably too late for this question, but how would you call this task? In gulp 4 `exports.deploy = deploy` results in `ReferenceError: deploy is not defined`

Comment: it was written for the older version of gulp. you will need to change the code slightly: check this example https://gist.github.com/kharandziuk/86d961b5ba9263ea8eb4d192cb5772d3 and try to merge it with the answer